# adding dropdown of 3rd table on 2nd table in form

Tags: python, web2py

model:

```
# coding: utf8
db.define_table('dept',
                Field('name',unique=True,label='Department Name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('course',
                Field('dept_id','reference dept'),
               Field('name',unique=True,label='Course Name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('files',
                Field('course_id', 'reference course'),
                Field('documentx','upload'))
```

controller:

```
def create_doc():
    form = SQLFORM(db.files).process(next=URL('show_doc'))
    return dict(form = form)
```

this works perfectly but the problem is when I open create_doc it shows a drop-down for courses only which is fine but how can I make it so that it asks to select department(in drop-down) then course(in drop-down) and then upload the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a detailed example of a ajax cascading dropdown lists in web2py here :
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1526/cascading-drop-down-lists-with-ajax-2

Other possibility here : http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_lazy_options_widget